# Manga the mc is transmigrated into villainess body and is dying of some fancy disease

Tags: story-identification, manga

She's put into the villainess's body, which is dying, though she does not feel the pain. Everybody else thinks she's in constant pain. They misunderstand her as a pitiful and tragic hero. She also vomits blood everyday

Comment: Was this in full colour, and what colour was her hair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[When the Villainess is in Love](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/when-the-villainess-is-in-love)*.

> When a young girl wakes up in the body of her favorite character, villainess Princess Libertia, the very first thing she decides to do is... fangirl her heart out! And why not? In a novel where all of her favorite characters are doomed to die, this is her chance to give them all a happy ending. But will the story play out as she expects when people start to see Princess Libertia in a new, forgiving light? One fangirl’s love might be what it takes to turn this villainess into a heroine!

The synopsis covers the villainess reincarnation. As part of the reincarnation, she inherits a magical fatal sickness from the original's body. However, the entire reincarnation is part of her cure.

[image]
[image]

Shortly after reincarnating, she consults a physician to get a proper diagnosis of the original character's fatal disease. With this, she plans to escape her duties and play around until she "dies", except she won't actually die. Since she's still coughing up blood and has been confirmed to have an uncurable disease, everyone just assumes she's bearing through it.

Comment: this is it ive been looking for it for a long while thank you qazmlpok