# Manhwa where the main character reincarnated as a white-haired girl that was cold to people. She was sick and has to find memories

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I'm looking for a manhwa where the main character is reincarnated as a white-haired girl that was cold to people and was sick. So people hated her, especially the male lead. The guys fall in love with her, but she learns she has to pick or remember memories from the girl she reincarnated as or she will die.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how she was sick? Do you mean that she was bedridden? Or would she occasionally cough up blood?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely *[When the Villainess is in Love](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/when-the-villainess-is-in-love)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264952/102326).

> When a young girl wakes up in the body of her favorite character, villainess Princess Libertia, the very first thing she decides to do is... fangirl her heart out! And why not? In a novel where all of her favorite characters are doomed to die, this is her chance to give them all a happy ending. But will the story play out as she expects when people start to see Princess Libertia in a new, forgiving light? One fangirl’s love might be what it takes to turn this villainess into a heroine!

The main character reincarnates as a "platinum blonde" villainess; not white hair, but still a light color.

The introduction explicitly mentions a sickness and finding memories: she needs to fuse with the soul of the original body, and will cough up blood until this completes.

[image: Cough up blood until find all the memories]

As the villainess character, she is initially hated by everyone, but wins them over, in part because they feel sorry for her suffering under a terminal disease, while in truth she feels no pain and isn't going to die.